# Android How to stop AlarmManager in other Activity

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I am using a service which is called in Activity 'A' repeatedly created by AlarmManager. My service is checking repeatedly response from server, when response is true new Activity B is started. Now when activity B is started i want to stop service as well as AlarmManager. how can i do this??

my 'A' activity code for calling service is following

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 40);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, response.class);

    // Add extras to the bundle
    intent.putExtra("foo", "bar");
    // Start the service
    // startService(intent);

    pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

    alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int i;
    i = 15;
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            i * 1000, pintent);

    startService(intent);
```

I have also tried this code snippet in Activity 'B' to stop AlarmManager but fail

```
      Intent sintent = new Intent(this, response.class);
     pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, sintent, 0);
     alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     stopService(sintent);
     alarm.cancel(pintent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Activity B you should create sIntent with the same context as you created it in Activity A.

So in Activity A I would add this

```
private static Context context;

public static Context getAppContext(){
    return ActivityA.context;
}
```

and inside onCreate() method of Activity A, initialize context

```
context=getApplicationContext();
```

And in Activity B create sIntent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.getAppContext(), ServiceClass.class);
intent.putExtra("fsasf", "bar");
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
stopService(intent);
alarm.cancel(pintent);
```

Comment: i can't get your that point create sintent with the same context as you created in Activity A

Comment: @Álvaro Pérez Soria Whats does this line mean? - "So Activity I would add this"