# Checking AlarmIntent from different Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager

I create a repeating alarm

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, NotificationService.class);
        intent.setAction(NotificationService.ACTION_PULL_NOTIFICATION);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), updateFrequency * 1000, pintent);
```

This works as intended so far. I check if my alarm is active with this

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.this, NotificationService.class);
    intent.setAction(NotificationService.ACTION_PULL_NOTIFICATION);
    return (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), ALARM_ID,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

This works fine as well. The problems arise when I need to check if my alarm is set from another activity (in my case the SettingsActivity).

I cannot check using the second function, because SettingsActivity has no access to "StartActivity.this", so I cannot recreate the same intent.

This should be simple stuff and I hope I missed something, but I tried multiple ways of setting up the intent so I can check its alarm in different activities but so far got no where. I found this answer: [Android How to stop AlarmManager in other Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27015294/android-how-to-stop-alarmmanager-in-other-activity) but it did not work for me either.

Is there a way to do this?

TL;DR: Create Alarm in Activity A, need to check if it's active in Activity B.

Comment: Try to use shared preference. for e.x. update a boolean true  then check the boolean value wherever(in any activity) you want

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea. Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem, because I also need to be able to cancel the Alarm from the SettingsActivity and I cannot be sure the user will navigate back to the StartActivity after disabling the alarm in the SettingsActivity.

Comment: I am getting slightly annoyed at Androids AlarmManager system. How hard can it be to add and retrieve alarms based on a unique alarm identifier tag instead of this "need-exact-same-intent" nonsense?! This looks like a serious lack of foresight to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using this code:

```
public static boolean isNotificationAlarmSet(Context context, int alarmId){
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    intent.setAction(NotificationService.ACTION_PULL_NOTIFICATION);
    return (PendingIntent.getService(context, alarmId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
}

public static void setNotificationAlarm(Context context, int alarmId, int frequency) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    intent.setAction(NotificationService.ACTION_PULL_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, alarmId, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), frequency, pintent);
}

public static void removeNotificationAlarm(Context context, int alarmId) {
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
    intent.setAction(NotificationService.ACTION_PULL_NOTIFICATION);
    PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getService(context, alarmId, intent, 0);
    if (p != null) {
        alarm.cancel(p);
        p.cancel();
    }
}
```

I found out that the provided context doesn't really matter, you can just use getApplicationContext();